# In powershell comparing 2 hashes

Tags: powershell

I am a powershell newbie. I wonder why the following code returns always 'false':

```
(get-filehash t2  | select-object hash) -eq (get-filehash t1  | select-object hash)
```

when

1. one file is a copy of the other
2. "get-filehash tn  | select-object hash" returns the same for both files
3. both files are in the same directory

Tnx in advance for your answer!

Comment: Because they are different objects. Add -ExpandProperty to your select

Comment: ... or compare properties directly: `(get-filehash t2).hash -eq (get-filehash t1).hash`

Answer (score 2):

When you use `| Select-Object Property` you end up with an object with a single property. Even though an object can have the same exact property and value, they are different objects. See the following example.

```
$a = [PSCustomObject]@{Property='A'}
$b = [PSCustomObject]@{Property='A'}

$a -eq $b

false
```

However, a reference to the object would be equal

```
$a = [PSCustomObject]@{Property='A'}
$b = $a

$a -eq $b

true
```

Instead, compare the actual property values.

```
$a = [PSCustomObject]@{Property='A'}
$b = [PSCustomObject]@{Property='A'}

$a.Property -eq $b.Property

true
```

With this info, any of the following will work.

```
(get-filehash t2).hash -eq (get-filehash t1).hash

(get-filehash t2  | Select-Object -ExpandProperty hash) -eq (get-filehash t1  | Select-Object -ExpandProperty hash)

(get-filehash t2  | select-object hash).hash -eq (get-filehash t1  | select-object hash).hash
```

You could also take advantage of powershell's capabilities.

```
$t1,$t2 = Get-ChildItem 'fileone','filetwo' | Get-FileHash

$t1.hash -eq $t2.hash
```

Comment: Thanks again Doug! your $t1,$t2 ... is a great help